# How do I find the last occurrence of a given sequence of numbers repetitively?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sequence in my Oracle database for example:

```
|Event code     | Event time    |
|41164          |  jan-20-2016  |
|41165          |  jan-21-2016  |
|41164          |  jan-27-2016  |
|41164          |  jan-30-2016  |
|41164          |  jan-31-2016  |
|41165          |  Feb-01-2016  |
|41164          |  Feb-03-2016  |
|41164          |  Feb-05-2016  |
|41165          |  Feb-01-2016  |
```

I need to return every occurrence of 41164 directly before the next 41165.

How would I do this with a  query?

Comment: With 'directly before' do you mean that dates must be contiguous? It would be useful if you could post desired result for your example

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Events (Event_code, Event_time ) AS
SELECT 41164, DATE '2016-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41165, DATE '2016-01-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41164, DATE '2016-01-27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41164, DATE '2016-01-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41164, DATE '2016-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41165, DATE '2016-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41164, DATE '2016-02-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41164, DATE '2016-02-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41165, DATE '2016-02-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query - Ordered by fetch order**:

```
SELECT Event_Code,
       Event_Time
FROM   (
  SELECT e.*,
         LEAD( Event_Code ) OVER ( ORDER BY ROWID ) as next_code
  FROM   Events e
)
WHERE  Event_Code = 41164
AND    Next_Code  = 41165;
```

**Output**:

```
EVENT_CODE EVENT_TIME        
---------- -------------------
     41164 2016-01-20 00:00:00 
     41164 2016-01-31 00:00:00 
     41164 2016-02-05 00:00:00
```

**Query - Ordered by date order**:

```
SELECT Event_Code,
       Event_Time
FROM   (
  SELECT e.*,
         LEAD( Event_Code ) OVER ( ORDER BY Event_Time ) as next_code
  FROM   Events e
)
WHERE  Event_Code = 41164
AND    Next_Code  = 41165;
```

**Output**:

```
EVENT_CODE EVENT_TIME        
---------- -------------------
     41164 2016-01-20 00:00:00 
     41164 2016-01-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated, requirement is not clear (For example, what should happen if more than these 2 numbers are available? If on next date you have both numbers, how you need to treat it ? etc )

You can start with and adapt below SQL:

```
select event_code from (
  select 
    event_code, 
    lead(event_code) over ( order by event_time ) next_event_code 
  from events )
where event_code < next_event_code;
```

NOTE: Written from memory, not tested

Answer (score 0):

This has been tested on oracle DB, you can run it without the DB and check if that is what you are looking for. Used [lead](http://with%20seq%20as%20%20%20(select%20%20%20%20%20%2041164%20a,%20'jan-20-2016'%20b%20%20%20%20from%20dual%20%20%20%20union%20%20%20%20select%20%20%20%20%20%2041165%20a,%20'jan-21-2016'%20b%20%20%20%20from%20dual%20%20%20%20union%20%20%20%20select%20%20%20%20%20%2041164%20a,%20'jan-27-2016'%20b%20%20%20%20from%20dual%20%20%20%20union%20%20%20%20select%20%20%20%20%20%2041164%20a,%20'jan-30-2016'%20b%20%20%20%20from%20dual%20%20%20%20union%20%20%20%20select%20%20%20%20%20%2041164%20a,%20'jan-31-2016'%20b%20%20%20%20from%20dual%20%20%20%20union%20%20%20%20select%20%20%20%20%20%2041165%20a,%20'Feb-01-2016'%20b%20%20%20%20from%20dual),%20lead%20as%20%20%20(select%20%20%20%20%20%20a,%20lead(a)%20over%20(order%20by%201)%20c,b%20%20%20%20from%20seq)%20select%20a,b%20from%20lead%20where%20a%20=%2041164%20and%20c=41165%20and%20rownum=1%20;) analytical function to get the result.

```
    with seq as
  (select
     41164 a, 'jan-20-2016' b
   from dual
   union
   select
     41165 a, 'jan-21-2016' b
   from dual
   union
   select
     41164 a, 'jan-27-2016' b
   from dual
   union
   select
     41164 a, 'jan-30-2016' b
   from dual
   union
   select
     41164 a, 'jan-31-2016' b
   from dual
   union
   select
     41165 a, 'Feb-01-2016' b
   from dual),
rown as
  (select
     a, to_date(b,'mon-dd-yyyy') d, b
   from seq),
lead as
  (select
     a, lead(a) over (order by d) c, b from rown)
select
  a, c, b
from lead
where
  a = 41164 and
  c=41165 ;
```

returns

```
   41164    41165   jan-20-2016
   41164    41165   jan-31-2016
```

Comment: Why `ROWNUM=1` when the OP asked for "I need to return every occurrence of 41164 directly before the next 41165"? Also, what did you intend the ordering to be with `ORDER BY 1` as this will result in a [non-deterministic ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#i97469).

Comment: @MT0 changed the answer. It should be correct now. Tested